# What are some correct ways to get up to a standing position from lying down?

Tags: movements

At the end of my Pilates routine, I transition between standing for pushups and lying on my back for various ab exercises.  (In Pilates, you start pushups from standing, bend over from your waist, and walk your body forward to a standard pushup position.)  What are some correct methods to transition from lying on your back to standing up and vice versa?

For a while I would lean over to one side, push off with my left arm until I got to a certain height, then lift up with my legs.  This was eventually making my left elbow sore though.  Now I do the following to stand up from lying down:

1. sit up from lying down to a cross-legged position
2. lean forward and put my arms out in front of me
3. raise myself up by pushing off with my legs
4. and finally uncross my legs once I'm standing

I reverse the process to get down.  Is this a "correct" (i.e., safe for my knees, back, etc.) method?  Are there other methods I can try?

Comment: Roll from back to front, get into pushup position, pull  knees up toward chest, stand up slowly.

Comment: That sounds fine. If you're interested in a different approach that is used to train strength in this movement you can look at [weighted Turkish get-ups](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/Kettlebell/KBTurkishGetup.html).

Comment: You could also research the "technical stand-up" or "proper stand" used in BJJ.

Comment: @Dave Liepman: Thanks!  I'm ignorant about martial arts, but the youtube video about technical stand-up that I saw looks really interesting.  Please post this as an answer and I'll at least vote for it.  Here's a youtube video demonstrating it: http://youtu.be/Thp7ipnjyTI

Comment: @Jack: Thanks for your answer.  I've been alternating between your suggestion and Dave's proper stand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two areas of physical culture that I'm familiar with that deal with how to stand up from lying on one's back are:

- Turkish get-ups (TGUs), using a weight
- The ["proper stand"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Thp7ipnjyTI) or "technical stand" used in Brazilian jiujitsu (BJJ) and judo

The TGU is an approach that is used to train strength, stability, and mobility. It is important to understand that [there are multiple ways to stand up in a Turkish get-up](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uGRBvom4Zrw).

The technical stand-up is a method used to protect oneself while getting back to one's feet in a fight, and as such it aims for maximum efficiency during the process. (For your purposes, the elements of the proper stand that address throwing or avoiding strikes can be ignored.)

Comment: Thanks, this looks helpful.  I'll try out the technical stand this week during my exercise routine and, if it works well, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: After trying it for a couple weeks I like the proper stand.  It provides a smooth and controlled motion to go from your back to standing.  I'm not as concerned with the kicking, as demonstrated in the YouTube video you reference, but the motion to standing is nice.  This is currently my favorite way to get up.

Answer (score 2):

There is a movement called "Kip-up", which takes you up to standing position from supine position. You use your body to throw you up to standing position in one movement. See wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kip-up. According to Parkour athlete [Ryan Doyle](http://youtu.be/vIj0NJBslhs?t=1m5s), this movement has been proved to be one of the fastest ways to get up.

Comment: Can you please try and explain that way in your own words? The link may be broken any day.

Comment: Doesn't seem to have to do with Pilates..

Comment: @Freakyuser yes, was in a hurry.

Comment: @FredrikD I was unsure if this question was Pilates-specific. The question was tagged "movement", therefore my answer!

Comment: I did not intend the question to be Pilates-specific, so thanks for this answer.  I'll keep your suggestion in mind (thus the upvote), but I'm not physically fit enough to do a kip-up.

Answer (score 0):

This might seem too good to be true but I had the same feeling when I read this point in the researched trusted article.

As far as I know, the best form and the most correct style of getting up from lied down to stand up position **is how a child who just-learned-to-get-up does**.

Most of the physical reactions and posture figures in the babies aren't biased by the modern life and bad habits yet and our instincts apparently does the best.

I would suggest Googling this video and checking some of them to get the exact idea. 
Meanwhile I will try to find the source of the article I have read this at and attach it to this answer for the added value of the answer.

The article below cannot be referred as a reference but worth checking. It highlights some good points. 
[Babies can do it, but most adults can’t](http://manbicep.com/2011/11/21/squat-form-babies-can-do-it-but-most-adults-cant/)

Comment: As my child ist still learning to get up, I'D aprpeciate if you could link the video or articel.

Comment: This is interesting, but I can't say it really answers my OP as your link points to a page that talks about squatting.  This addresses a subset of getting up from lying down, but not the whole movement, in particular what interests me most (which would be, I guess, getting to that squatting position).  The original article you reference might be helpful though.

Comment: I'll remember to find you the reference. I still found the proper squatting move quite interesting.

Comment: By the way, healthy baby can hold itself on his mother just using hands, and adults were supposed to keep that skill (ie: being able to climb using only your arms... As I write that, I cannot do.it, I am too fat and too weak  :( )

Comment: Babies are also proportioned really differently from adults.  For instance, they have huge heads.